# Twitter Kit not Integrated using fabric

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, twitter-fabric, social-media

I am trying from last few days to integrate twitter kit in my project using fabric SDK. But i got an error " **Whoops, something went wrong here! please contact support@fabric.io** " i am using fabric(2.3.0), Xcode(7.2), OS X (10.11.2).

> Here is my steps
>
> - Login to fabric.io
> - Create Organization from ([link](https://fabric.io/settings))
> - Download fabric SDK ([download link](https://fabric.io/downloads))
> - Create New Xcode project
> - Run fabric SDK
> - login -> +New App -> Select Xcode project -> select Organization -> Select a kit to install(here i choose Twitter Kit to install and Hit install button for integrate with my project.)

See
[image]

Can anyone help me out from this problem
Thanks in advance

Comment: how you resolved this issue

Comment: @nivritgupta did you test under the secure network?

Comment: i figure our the issue this fabric app does not work properly with mac OSX Sierra , i am able to install  the SDK if i am using El-Captain :-)

Answer (score 2):

Solved it by quitting Xcode before starting the Fabric app

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue.
Have resolved it using step-by-step Fabric tutorial
https://fabric.io/kits/ios/twitterkit/install 
(especially pay attention to Step 3: Account Provisioning and Terms of Service)

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Fabric, remove `Fabric-latest.zip` and  re-download it again should work.

Answer (score 0):

I observe some time due to slow internet connection fabric app not working as expected.

so the easiest solution is to visit fabric side and follow cocoa pod installation steps

here is the link..

https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install

https://fabric.io/kits/ios/twitterkit/install

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

To install using CocoaPods, just add `pod 'TwitterKit'` to your Podfile and run `pod install` (or `pod update TwitterKit` if you just want the latest version).

If you are just looking to download the Framework and install yourself you can find the download link here: https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/installation#install-twitter-kit-manually

You can find installation instructions here: https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/installation